# Converting flat indices to 3D indices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, indices

I have an array of flat indices and I want to get the corresponding 3D indices. I want to avoid using a for-loop to convert each flat index to a 3D index one by one.

I tried to use the numpy's `np.unravel_index()` method to compute the 3D indices as shown below:

```
   import numpy as np

   # Column vector of flat indices
   test_flat_indices = np.array([[3957], [8405], [9161], [11105], [969]])

   # Shape of 3D array
   num_rows = 51
   num_cols = 51
   num_frames = 8

   # Convert flat indices to 3D indices
   indices_3d = np.unravel_index(test_flat_indices, (num_rows, num_cols, num_frames))

   # Format the result to [row, col, frame] format
   indices_3d = np.column_stack(np.array(indices_3d))

   print(indices_3d)
```

The above code produces the following **output**:

```
   array([[ 9, 35,  5],
          [20, 30,  5],
          [22, 23,  1],
          [27, 11,  1],
          [ 2, 19,  1]], dtype=int64)
```

**Problem:** The above out seems wrong because if I try to convert the 3D indices above to flat indices back (for verification) then, the values does not match. For example, the output value `[9, 35, 5]` should represent 9th-row, 35th-column and 5th-frame, which would actually result in `(5x51x51 + 9x51 + 35) = 13499`, which is wrong (the correct value should be 3957).

**NOTE:** If I change the `unravel_index()` method arguments to `np.unravel_index(test_flat_indices, (num_frames, num_rows, num_cols))` then, the output is correct, which is:

```
   array([[ 1, 26, 30],
          [ 3, 11, 41],
          [ 3, 26, 32],
          [ 4, 13, 38],
          [ 0, 19,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

but why do I need to put the number of frames first?

Comment: The rightmost 3D-index moves most quickly (for C order), meaning +1 increment in 3D index is +1 in linear index, for second-to-rightmost +1 in 3D is +8 (rightmost dimension of shape) in linear and so on. For e. g. `[9, 35, 5]` this is the linear index `9*8*51 + 35*8 + 5 = 3957`. The leftmost dimension in `shape` doesn't even matter.

Comment: Use the actual shape of your array. You haven't show any, so we can only guess in the dark here. But I am pretty sure the actual shape of your array isn't `(num_rows, num_cols, num_frames)` but `(num_frames, num_rows, num_cols)`. Those indices come from somewhere (I mean in the actual code, not the mre). There is an array A, from which they were computed. Use `A.shape` as argument for `unravel_index`